# How to solve $\int_0^1 t^k e^{\alpha t}\, \mathrm dt$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Calculate the following definite integral:

$$\int_0^1 t^k e^{\alpha t}\,\mathrm dt \ \ \ \alpha\in \mathbb R$$

I have to apply the integration by parts, but I can not write the result in a compact expression.

Comment: What conditions are satisfied by $k$ ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\textbf{another hint}$
$$
\int_0^1t^k\mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} dt = \frac{d^k}{d\alpha^k}\int_0^1\mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} dt.
$$

$\textbf{edit:}$
As pointed out correctly by @FelixMarin this method is only valid for $k>0$.

Comment: The OP didn't say that $k$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @felixmarin very true. I shall edit it to be clear that I am talking about $k>0$. If it was not the case then I shall gladly remove this hint.

Comment: Don't remove anything. Please. You already got the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** : Let $I_k$ be your integral, then by the integration by parts you'll have
$$I_k=\int_{0}^{1}t^k\left(\frac{e^{\alpha t}}{\alpha}\right)'dt=\cdots =\frac{e^{\alpha}}{\alpha}-\frac k\alpha I_{k-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to Chinny84's hint,

$$\int_0^1t^k\mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} dt = \frac{d^k}{d\alpha^k}\int_0^1\mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} dt=\frac{d^k}{d\alpha^k}\left(\frac{e^\alpha-1}{\alpha} \right)=\frac{d^k}{d\alpha^k}\left( e^\alpha \cdot \alpha^{-1}\right)-\frac{d^k}{d\alpha^k}\alpha^{-1}$$

$$=\frac{d^k}{d\alpha^k}\left( e^\alpha \cdot \alpha^{-1}\right)- (-1)^k\frac{k!}{\alpha^{k+1}}$$

For $\frac{d^k}{d\alpha^k}\left( e^\alpha \cdot \alpha^{-1}\right)$, use $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(f g)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}f^{(n-k)}g^{(k)}$, with $f=e^\alpha,g=\alpha^{-1}$.

$$\int_0^1t^k\mathrm{e}^{\alpha t} dt=\frac{d^k}{d\alpha^k}\left( e^\alpha \cdot \alpha^{-1}\right)- (-1)^k\frac{k!}{\alpha^{k+1}}=e^\alpha\sum\limits_{j=0}^k(-1)^j{k \choose j}\frac{j!}{\alpha^{j+1}}-(-1)^k\frac{k!}{\alpha^{k+1}}$$

Comment: A lovely wrap up of the hint. Thank you :)!! Keep up the great work.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^1 t^k e^{\alpha t}dt=\int_0^1 t^k \left ( \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{a} \right )'dt= \\ \left [ t^k  \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{a} \right ]_0^1-\int_0^1 kt^{k-1} \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{a} dt= \\ \frac{e^{\alpha }}{a} -\int_0^1 kt^{k-1} \left ( \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{a^2} \right )'dt= \\ \frac{e^{\alpha }}{a} - \left [kt^{k-1} \left ( \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{a^2} \right ) \right ] _0^1+\int_0^1 k(k-1)t^{k-2}  \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{a^2} dt= \\ \frac{e^{\alpha }}{a} - k  \frac{e^{\alpha }}{a^2} +k(k-1) \int_0^1 t^{k-2}  \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{a^2} dt= \\ 
\frac{e^{\alpha }}{a} - k  \frac{e^{\alpha }}{a^2} +k(k-1) \int_0^1 t^{k-2}  \left (\frac{e^{\alpha t}}{a^3} \right )' dt= \\ 
\frac{e^{\alpha }}{a} - k  \frac{e^{\alpha }}{a^2} +k(k-1) \left [  t^{k-2}\frac{e^{\alpha t}}{a^3} \right ]_0^1-k(k-1)(k-2) \int_0^1 t^{k-3}  \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{a^3}  dt= \\
\frac{e^{\alpha }}{a} - k  \frac{e^{\alpha }}{a^2} +k(k-1)\frac{e^{\alpha }}{a^3} -k(k-1)(k-2) \int_0^1 t^{k-3}  \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{a^3}  dt
$$

Can you continue?